# Stripe events: How to capture the product that was successfully paid with Stripe events and a webhook?

Tags: stripe-payments

My website's users will buy credits using Stripe's single-payment workflow with a checkout session. They can buy single credits or credit packages, like 10 credits package at discount price.
After a successfully payment I want to capture the event with a webhook and update the user balance according to the product and quantity paid by the user.

I'm currently tracking `payment_intent.succeeded` events and I can see payment and charge information however I can't find any information related to the product ordered. What am I missing? Thank you.

This is an example of the payment intent event I'm capturing:

```
{
  "amount": 5250,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_received": 5250,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "charges": {
    "data": [
      {
        "amount": 5250,
        "amount_captured": 5250,
        "amount_refunded": 0,
        "application": null,
        "application_fee": null,
        "application_fee_amount": null,
        "balance_transaction": "txn_1HUSonCfZ37XLQD8mLERR2YR",
        "billing_details": {
          "address": {
            "city": null,
            "country": "JP",
            "line1": null,
            "line2": null,
            "postal_code": null,
            "state": null
          },
          "email": "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com",
          "name": "asd",
          "phone": null
        },
        "calculated_statement_descriptor": "XXX XXXX",
        "captured": true,
        "created": 1600847712,
        "currency": "jpy",
        "customer": "cus_I4c27DIUQuvAHQ",
        "description": null,
        "destination": null,
        "dispute": null,
        "disputed": false,
        "failure_code": null,
        "failure_message": null,
        "fraud_details": {},
        "id": "ch_1HUSomCfZ37XLQD8d133buOK",
        "invoice": null,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {},
        "object": "charge",
        "on_behalf_of": null,
        "order": null,
        "outcome": {
          "network_status": "approved_by_network",
          "reason": null,
          "risk_level": "normal",
          "risk_score": 39,
          "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
          "type": "authorized"
        },
        "paid": true,
        "payment_intent": "pi_1HUSoWCfZ37XLQD82vnE1yQT",
        "payment_method": "pm_1HUSolCfZ37XLQD8gSn0oy4x",
        "payment_method_details": {
          "card": {
            "brand": "visa",
            "checks": {
              "address_line1_check": null,
              "address_postal_code_check": null,
              "cvc_check": "pass"
            },
            "country": "US",
            "exp_month": 11,
            "exp_year": 2050,
            "fingerprint": "uaJa23vzDgA7fnSC",
            "funding": "credit",
            "installments": null,
            "last4": "4242",
            "network": "visa",
            "three_d_secure": null,
            "wallet": null
          },
          "type": "card"
        },
        "receipt_email": null,
        "receipt_number": null,
        "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1HU77uCfZ37XLQD8/ch_1HUSomCfZ37XLQD8d133buOK/rcpt_I4c233eGeSYOaN9cPvncC4AcU2Sm4s7",
        "refunded": false,
        "refunds": {},
        "review": null,
        "shipping": null,
        "source": null,
        "source_transfer": null,
        "statement_descriptor": null,
        "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
        "status": "succeeded",
        "transfer_data": null,
        "transfer_group": null
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1HUSoWCfZ37XLQD82vnE1yQT"
  },
  "client_secret": "pi_1HUSoWCfZ37XLQD82vnE1yQT_secret_XXX",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1600847696,
  "currency": "jpy",
  "customer": "cus_I4c27DIUQuvAHQ",
  "description": null,
  "id": "pi_1HUSoWCfZ37XLQD82vnE1yQT",
  "invoice": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_action": null,
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": "pm_1HUSolCfZ37XLQD8gSn0oy4x",
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

Comment: the payment happens on your website or on the preconfigured pages that stripe offers?

Comment: @Berto99 I'm using the stripe checkout session

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've put the product details in the `line_items` of the Checkout session you created ([see guide step](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#create-a-checkout-session)), then what you're looking for is how to "fulfill the order" ([see guide step](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill)), which you can do by listening to [`checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) events.

When you receive an event, the event [`data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data) will be a Checkout session by id, and you can then [retrieve that session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) and specify [`expand\[\]=line_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) to be able to inspect the [`line_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) for the session.

Update: I modified the above to reflect that `line_items` is not included by default. You must retrieve the session and include it in an expand.

Comment: I'm passing `price_id` in `line_items` to reference a product and price. None of them are included in `data` from the `checkout.session.completed` or `payment_intent.succeeded` events

Comment: Pardon me, the `line_items` are not attached by default, they must be requested during a retrieval with `expand` (so they are not in the event data). I updated my answer above.