# Stripe webhooks, how can I receive the PRICE item when the product paid for is not a subscription but a one-time payment?

Tags: webhooks, stripe-payments

I have 1 product in Stripe with 2 prices

- 1st price is a recurring subscription
- 2nd price is a one-time payment

I process both by using `redirectToCheckout`, the first one with `mode: subscription` and the second one with `mode: payment`, and both indicating in `lineItems` the respective price codes

Then, when the payment is fulfilled on Stripe's side, I get webhooks sent to my php backend

With the 1st item I get the event type `customer.subscription.created`, and the info sent in that webhook **includes** the price code

I need this price code to be sure that the user has fulfilled the payment for that specific `price` item

The problem is with the 2nd item, I've been able to identify 4 events that are sent with the **webhooks** after payment:

- `customer.created`
- `charge.succeeded`
- `payment_intent.succeeded`
- `checkout.session.completed`

And none of them include the `price` information about what product the user has paid for

Probably I could ask stripe for that information in a `fetch` operation, but ... it is impossible that there isn't any webhook that includes this basic (?) information

Or maybe I'm understanding it wrongly?

EDIT:

Probably the answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64028153/826815), so that the webhook (`checkout.session.completed`) by default is not including this information, and it indeed has to be retrieved in a 2nd step

Comment: For the recurring subscription you would want to listen for the `invoice.paid` event which will include the price ID under `invoice.lines.data[].price` - this information should be readily available on the event. For the one-time payment you would want to listen for the `customer.session.completed` event and retrieve the session with the line_items expanded. Here's an example: https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties. The price will be under `line_items.data.price`. I'd also recommend the docs for tracking active subs: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#tracking

Comment: Thanks, indeed the first link explains it very well, maybe you want to format this as an aswer (or I can do it). That said, it is not consistent that what you get by default in a subscription webhook is not default in a one-time payment webhook, maybe in a future api update stripe decides to add prices as default info everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ttmarek has said, the answer is here https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties indicating that one has to retrieve this information if using a `single payment`

If using a `subscription` this info is included by default and there's no need to start another request

An alternative to avoid this extra request could be using the `amount` charged (which comes with most webhooks), provided that you can identify your price from this amount