# how to get the email of the user that paid?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to get the email of the user whenever there's any payment made
my app flow is as the following, when the user clicks on the link, this supabase edge function will get called:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      mode: "payment",
      line_items: [{
        price_data: {
          currency: "",
          product_data: {
            name: "",
          },
          unit_amount: "",
        },
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      success_url: `${Deno.env.get("CLIENT_URL")}/success.html`,
      cancel_url: `${Deno.env.get("CLIENT_URL")}/cancel.html`,
    });
```

and after the user successful payment this webhook will receieve the payment details but it will not get the email of the user

```
serve(async (req) => {
  const signature = req.headers.get("Stripe-Signature");
  const body = await req.text();
  let receivedEvent;
  try {
    receivedEvent = await stripe.webhooks.constructEventAsync(
      body,
      signature,
      Deno.env.get("STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SIGNING_SECRET"),
      undefined,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err",err);
    return new Response(err.message, { status: 400 });
  }
  console.log("the event", receivedEvent);
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ ok: true }), { status: 200 });
});
```

what should I do?
I see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026871/stripe-events-how-to-capture-the-product-that-was-successfully-paid-with-stripe) but I don't know how he was able to get the email

Comment: You are supposed to pass the email to Stripe yourself. So for example, you would add the email to your body like so `req.body.email`  You can then add that to your `stripe.checkout.session`. ideally you would want to get your email from your state management tool e.g redux, Context API

Comment: but I don't have access to the user email, that's why I think I can't follow this approach

Comment: When you say you don't have access to the email what do you mean?  Is there anywhere on your frontend where the user enters their email address?

Comment: the user will enter his email in the stripe email input only, not before that, I want to get that email after there's a successful payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `checkout.session.completed` event, you will be able to find customer's email in `customer_details.email` field: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_details-email